# Azure Function and self hosted SignalR server

Tags: .net, signalr, azure-functions

I know it's possible to use SignalR in a Function using the Azure SignalR Service, like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp

But is it possible to use it in a Function with a self hosted SignalR server ?

Comment: AzureFunctions have a limited runtime so why do you want to setup a server in an environment which has a limited "time to live" (of maybe minutes)? Can you explain your need for that a bit further please.

Comment: SignalR would be hosted in an App Service, not in a Function. Functions would be used only to send SignalR messages to the App Service